# 'Array' is not identical to 'Array<T>' Why this is coming in following code?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have to select the value from Array and assign it to the String variable.

```
var selectedCountryCode:String = ""
var countryCodesArray:Array = ["+1","+977","+93","+355","+213","+1684"]
```

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, I need to store the selected value in the variable according to the indexPath as follows but I am getting the `**'Array' is not identical to 'Array<T>'**`  error.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    selectedCountryCode = countryCodesArray[indexPath.row]  //Here issue is coming

    println(selectedCountryCode)
}
```

Please let me know what is the cause and logic behind the issue and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var countryCodesArray: [String] = ["+1","+977","+93","+355","+213","+1684"]
```

or even better

```
var countryCodesArray = ["+1","+977","+93","+355","+213","+1684"]
```

The above shouldn't even compile since you're missing the generic parameter.

Comment: That's what I thought too but the above example works in a Playground!

Comment: @RajeevBhatia That's weird. That could be the cause though.

Comment: Side notes: 1. let type inference do the work, you can remove the variable type: `var countryCodesArray = ["+1","+977","+93","+355","+213","+1684"]` - 2. this: `var selectedCountryCode:String = ""` looks like an ideal candidate for an optional type: `var selectedCountryCode: String?`

Comment: Yeah @Antonio that is a good solution. I wonder why it is working in the playground though

Comment: @RajeevBhatia Probably a bug.